# simple .load of html files not so simple

Tags: jquery, html

having a bit of difficulty loading html content into a div.

I tried to emulate what was going on in this post:
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/64192/loading-div-sections-from-separate-files

Instead of loading the content inside the #target div, the link just opens the content separately.

My javascript is:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#but_edu").click(function(){
$("#target").load("education.txt", aviso);
});
});
</script>
```

My HTML is:

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<section id="headTop">
<img src="img/ap_logo2.png" alt=""/>
</section>
<section id="headNav">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="row" id="navigation" style="margin-top:60px;">

                <div class="col-md-3 txtCenter"><a href="#" id="but_edu">  <img class="gradPic" src="img/grad.png"alt=""/></a>
                        </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 txtCenter"><a href="ajax/experience.html" id="but_exp"><img class="gradPic" src="img/exp.png" alt=""/></a>
                        </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 txtCenter"><a href="ajax/skills.html" id="but_skill"><img class="gearPic" src="img/gear.png" alt=""/></a>
                        </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 txtCenter"><a href="ajax/projects.html"     id="but_proj"><img class="gradPic" src="img/exp.png" alt=""/></a>
                        </div>
                            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        </div>
</section><!--HeadNav Section Ends-->
<section id="cHold">
    <div id="target"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: what is the `aviso` argument to the load function for?

Comment: i deleted it. seems to be a remnant of old code.

Comment: did that fix the problem then? if not, can you explain what you mean by "the link just opens the content separately" ??

Comment: Like the normal behavior of a link. It loads education.html but not in the div or on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it works to me:

http://jsfiddle.net/eetfqy9y/

*HTML*

```
<section id="headNav">
    <a href="#" id="but_edu">Click me!</a>
</section>

<section id="cHold">
    <div id="target"></div>
</section>
```

*Javascript*

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#but_edu").click(function () {
        $("#target").load("//fiddle.jshell.net");
    });
});
```

One thing to be cautious of is to make sure that your load URL is valid. You can open up your JavaScript console (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> for me) and check if the request 404's.

Comment: I see no reason why you can't reuse the same script with a different (content) argument.